# Operator XOR and float variables

Tags: floating-point, vb6, xor

I decided to make a funny cryptographic program for personal use.
 I want to cypher FLOATING POINT (Single) variables!

But, of course, it doesn't work.

Well, integer values worked correctly, but singles did not. I lost all commas and precision.
I tried to inject ASM code, but it didn't work.
Do you know any method to make this work correctly?

```
Dim MyData as Single, MyKey as Single 'Long didnt work too

MyData = 0.0017627
Key = 17.1278

MyData = MyData XOR Key

'After this I lost my data!
MyData = MyData XOR Key
```

Okay, you may say something like "use C++ and do not copulate brain", but I prefer to use VB6.

Oh, if there's something useful in VB.NET, I can install it on my new notebook dated 2010.

Answer (score 1):

While the VB6 documentation states that the `Xor` operator requires numeric variables (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa242859(v=vs.60)), it really means integer or long variables.

You're losing the precision of your `Single` because the operator is performing a conversion to the integer type, essentially this:

```
MyData = CLng(MyData) Xor CLng(Key)
```

You can see this better if you `Xor` a floating point value with 0, which will retain the bit pattern as it's used by the operator (after the implicit integer conversion).

```
Debug.Print 0 Xor 45.2     ' result: 45
Debug.Print 0 Xor 45.7     ' result: 46  (rounds up)
```